# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape' occurs in PyCharm but program functions perfectly in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, deep-learning, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error

I'm following a tutorial on deep learning and I used Jupyter Notebook to follow along. The program ran with no issues. However, when I copied my code into PyCharm after installing all the necessary libraries, I ran the code and at the very end, after running through the training, this error appeared: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'. Can anybody tell me why this error occurs and how to fix it?

Tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wQ8BIBpya2k&t=1s

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

fashion_mnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test = tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax))

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20)
model.save('epic_clothes_identifier')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("epic_clothes_identifier")
predictions = new_model.predict([x_test])
print(np.argmax(predictions[0]))
```

Comment: Show the relevant code as an [mcve], and the full error with trace. Apparently you're trying to call `shape` on a list somewhere, or passing a list where an array is expected.

Comment: What line (in your example) does the `AttributeError` occur on?